# Prove a consistent matrix is still consistent after row operations have been performed on it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-explanation

If a row operation is done to a consistent linear system, the resulting system must be consistent.

How can I prove this if it is true?

Thanks

Comment: Row operations correspond to multiplication on the left by invertible matrices, thus the linear system must be consistent after a row operation.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking kinda the same thing.